How can I access the frame buffer in iOS 17
I wanted to ask how to access and modify the frame buffer in iOS 17.
I want to modify the entire screen to create black bars on the top of the screen, to decrease the total screen size and resize the entire content of the screen accordingly.
How could I do this? I have not found any information on how to modify the frame buffer under iOS 17.

While you can't directly modify the frame buffer in iOS 17, you can achieve your goal using layout techniques, view overlays, or additional window layers in SwiftUI and UIKit.

Could you explain further what you mean by "using layout techniques, view overlays and additional window layers"? How would I use these to implement black bars on the entire system and apps?
